# How can I create a character array in Java without a specified length?

Tags: java

```
    char ret[] = {};
```

Doesn't work seem to work and I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are wanna a dynamic array. If `specified length` means dynamic length, you should set the length with a variable. So the length will not be fixed by constant value, while it will be set at runtime. `char[] ret = new char[size]`. The size will be set at runtime.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're probably looking for an `ArrayList<Character>`.

Answer (score 19):

Arrays **must** have a fixed length.

If your goal is to have a dynamically expansible list, consider a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) instead. Everytime you add an item by `add()` method, it will grow dynamically whenever needed.

```
List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/TOC.html) > [Trail: Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) > [The List Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html)

Answer (score 6):

```
char[] ret = new char[0];
```

this will create an empty array. But you can use it only as a placeholder for cases when you don't have an array to pass.

If you don't know the size initially, but want to add to the array, then use an `ArrayList<Character>`

Answer (score 4):

The best way to have an extensible array of char without the overhead of an Character object for each char, is to use a StringBuilder.  This allows you to build an array of char in a wide variety of ways. Once you are finished you can use getChars() to extract a copy of the char[].

Comment: ^ for idea other than collection and i  think buffer have  a less over head.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians this is what we do. We have a buffer of 8-bit characters which can be off heap.

Answer (score 3):

you should use:

```
char[] ret = {};
```

Comment: irrelevent.user was asking for runtime char Array?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create an array without a length only with a length of 0, and why would u want that?

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't really make sense; an array always has some length.  But is this what you were thinking of?

```
char[] ret = null;
```

This creates a *reference* to an array, but initialises it to `null`.  There is no actual array yet.

Answer (score 1):

Methinks you are still thinking in C or Pascal. The functionality you want is probably a Java String. `char[]` is uncommon in Java. (You can iterate through the chars of a string with `charAt`, among other possibilities.)

Answer (score 0):

You probably come from PHP or another programming language that hasn't got real arrays. (An array in PHP is a sort of dictionary/hashmap)

Arrays in JAVA are fixed length.

For no fixed length, you can use a Vector. If you want to index with something else than integers from 0 to length, you can use a Dictionary.

Comment: +0: IMHO `Vector` is a legacy class which was replaced in Java 1.2 (1998) by `List` Similarly Dictionary was replaced by Map. In the Javadoc for Dictionary it states `NOTE: This class is obsolete.  New implementations should implement the Map interface, rather than extending this class.`

Comment: Hey Peter, I had no idea, thanks for that info! I'm actually more of a C# dev so I looked up the equivalent Java classes but I had no idea that Vector<> and Dictionary<,> where obsolete and replaced, well spotted!

Comment: Java is often very slow to phase out "legacy" classes.